# Comparing 2 times with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, time, parseint

Thanks in advance for any help...

I'm trying to (1) generate a begin time and end time for a form, (2) find the difference between the two, and (3) add the difference to a new input.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<a href="#" id="starttime">Begin time</a>
<input id="starttimeinput" name="starttimeinput" type="text" value="">
<script>
    $("#starttime").click(function () {
         var begintime = event.timeStamp;
         $("#starttimeinput").val(begintime);
    });
</script>
<a href="#" id="endtime">end time</a>
<input id="endtimeinput" name="endtimeinput" type="text" value="">
<script>
    $("#endtime").click(function () {
         var endtime = event.timeStamp;
         $("#endtimeinput").val(endtime);
    });
</script>
<input id="totaltime" name="totaltime" type="text">
<script>
    $("#totaltime").focus(function () {
       var begintime = $("#starttimeinput").val();
       var endtime = $("#endtimeinput").val();
       var totaltime = endtime - begintime;
       $("#totaltime").val(totaltime); 
     });     
</script>
```

The first part works (entering the timestamps into the beginning time and end time inputs). I've never worked with numbers before and can't figure out the second part. The result that comes up is "NaN".

Also this might be useful to know the the time between when the links are clicked should be around 30 seconds...

Thanks much for any help you guys have answered so many questions of mine without me having to post!

Comment: Check this  http://api.jquery.com/event.timeStamp/

Comment: The first part don't work for me and even generating a error. last input gets 0, though. And if I add event param to click callback functions, everything works just as you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the times back out, otherwise they're just strings (as returned by `.val()`).

```
$("#totaltime").focus(function () {
    var begintime = parseInt($("#starttimeinput").val(), 10),
        endtime = parseInt($("#endtimeinput").val(), 10),
        totaltime = endtime - begintime;
    $("#totaltime").val(totaltime); 
 });
```

---

Personally, I'd sooner just store the `begintime` and `endtime` values myself, rather than in text inputs (why does the user need to see them, anyway?). Like this:

```
var begintime,
    endtime;
$("#starttime").click(function (event) {
     begintime = event.timeStamp;
     //$("#starttimeinput").val(begintime);
});

$("#endtime").click(function (event) {
     endtime = event.timeStamp;
     //$("#endtimeinput").val(endtime);
});

$("#totaltime").focus(function () {
    $("#totaltime").val(endtime - begintime); 
});
```

---

On a side note, I would recommend moving your jQuery code out of inline `<script>` tags and into an external JS file. This makes for more maintainable markup and JS. Just wrap all of your JS code in a document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* your code here */
});
```

or, more concisely,

```
$(function () {
    /* your code here */
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately when I focus, instead of returning NaN it doesn't show anything...

Comment: @Andy: see my edit. It looks like you (and consequently, I) omitted the event callback parameter `event`.

Comment: I believe the minus operation automatically converts strings to numbers.

Comment: Alright... this is what I was looking for thanks a bunch you're a champion.

Comment: @Box9: you are correct, but I can't see a good reason to use type coercion over true parsing in this case. I am wondering, then, why the OP saw `NaN`...

Comment: @Andy: you're welcome. Looks like it was just the missing parameter: as Box9 pointed out, you can get away with letting `-` (the subtraction operator) coerce the strings to numbers.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on making the result of the comparison (i.e. $("#totaltime").val(endtime - begintime); ) into its own variable so I can do more with it... like say something if it is more than 30 seconds. Thanks. I don't understand why: var totaltime = endtime - begintime doesn't work.

Comment: @Matt yeah, I couldn't figure out the `NaN` part either; I would have expected an error. Parsing vs. type coercion is a matter of preference, however keep in mind that `parseInt(val)` will successfully parse "10a" as "10" when it probably should be `NaN`. You can use `Number(val)` instead if you prefer to explicitly convert your strings ;)